# .gitignore per branch (easy), ignoring opposite folders, WITHOUT deleting them when switching branches (not so easy)

Tags: git, branch, gitignore, branching-and-merging

### Problem

I would like to have one 'wwwroot' repo for my iis server, with different branches tracking different 'sites', specifically a production site (wwwroot/prod), a dev site (wwwroot/dev) and perhaps some other sites (wwwroot/other).

I assumed it would be trivial to simply have each branch track only it's respective folder, ignoring the other subfolders.  This "works", **except** switching between branches **deletes** the *other* branches.

I've tried simple .gitignores that ignore the other directories by name, and more complex .gitignores that ignore *everything but* the respective directory.

I'm not worried about .gitignore file merge conflicts if/when I decide to merge branches.

I imagine I could use the solution posed elsewhere on SO using different excludes and updating the symlink on branch change, but I don't think that's ideal for long-term/anyone who replaces me.  Surely I'm just using .gitignore wrong?

---

### Example

```
wwwroot/prod   (tracked by prod branch, ignores dev and other)
wwwroot/dev    (tracked by dev branch, ignores prod and other)
wwwroot/other  (tracked by other branch, ignores prod and dev)
```

but for example, after setting up the gitignores, changing to a different branch causes the other (previously checked out) branch to be removed from wwwroot working directory (and thus the web pages are no longer accessible)

Comment: You can't (quite) get what you want, because files that are in a commit are ... in a commit. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331727/1256452) for details (and what you *can* do).

Comment: Thank you - "you are telling Git: Remove everything related to the current commit and switch to the other commit." - guess the answer is rather obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to *not* track wwwroot content (meaning that folder or series of folders does not need to be tracked in Git, in commits, but can remain private), then I would:

- create those folders outside your repo
- track symlinks

That is

- `wwwroot  -> /../prod`   (`prod` is a folder in the same parent folder than the repo itself)
- `wwwroot  -> /../dev`   (`dev` is a folder in the same parent folder than the repo itself)
- `wwwroot  -> /../other`   (`other` is a folder in the same parent folder than the repo itself)

That way, you only track `wwwroot`, which changes depending on the branch, and symlink to the right external folder, using a relative path.